# Optimization db queries - scaling big data - Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, chunks

I've been working on a web-app that uses Laravel 5. It's running on localhost (xampp) on a windows 8.1 PC. 4GB RAM, 2,67GHz processor, pretty simple.

The table I'm querying most of the times contains a lot of rows (10.000 give or take) - so many that to write a route that does:

```
return User::all();
```

Running this just returns a white screen. Sometimes Chrome console lists a 500 (Internal Server error).

Echoes or prints made before the query are shown but nothing after that is executed. Querying another model (whose table only has 2 rows) returns the data correctly.

Which leads me to conclude that my server isn't scaling well for this amount of data. I'm trying to fix this by doing.

```
User::all()->chunk(200, function($chunkOfTickets){ /*some code*/});
```

which I expected would split the data into chunks to make it easier on the server. This doesn't work, however, because Eloquent is first fetching all the data (and breaking because it can't handle it) and only then dividing it into chunks.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: just tested over and over, requesting increasingly greater ammounts of data. The limit is 26000 rows approximately (27000 and out of memory error is returned).

As stated in the comments the php log states this. Apparently I was requesting so much memory it crashed before Laravel could show the error message

```
[01-Jul-2015 17:27:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8376445 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gamescaffold\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php on line 791
```

**Extra Edit**

Is there a way I can divide in chunks the reply from the DB? like:

```
User::chunk(200)->all(); /*which obviously does not work*/
```

If I write a seemingly complex query to the database directly through phpMyAdmin it's returning 37035 rows in 0.0045 seconds. (I suspect there's some under the hood optimizations here by xampp or something though)

Comment: what does the php error log show when you get the 500 internal server errors? also 10K rows is not "that" much or that "big" of a data

Comment: thanks for pointing me out to php error logs, I was forgetting those (I just checked Laravel's own logs which are empty). The entries say something like `[01-Jul-2015 14:49:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gamescaffold\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 296`

Comment: there you have it, 10K records eating up the allowed memory for a php process around 128MB, depending on your business logic increase this or optimize the way you fetch the data, do you actually need to grab all 10k and show them ?

Comment: I'm already limiting the data I'm fetching by defining start and end dates and one extra logic-related filter (a "state"). But it's still too much apparently.

Comment: Have you also indexed the relevant fields?

Comment: on a side note, I noticed the timestamp in the logs is not one hour late. But windows clock is correct. Could this be the reason for some issue?

Comment: @Quasdunk I don't understand the question. Eloquent is handling the queries. It's a relational database, I think all queries are done based on the id

Comment: @Thaenor Yes, Laravel builds the queries for you, but it's also important to set indexes on the tables for cloumns that are queried often. If you're not familiar with that, you should definitely read up on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index - querying only the id and not many records might not be a big of a deal, but as soon as you take other constraints into account, indexes can improve the performance enormously.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the query actually kills it or is it upon returning the response? Because the query itself shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds or so, 10k records isn't really much. If you're returning the results derictly, the automatic casting to Json might take quite some time and memory (not sure about that though). Concerning the chunks, `User::paginate(100);` is probably what you're looking for (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#basic-usage)

Comment: Yeah... It's not about the speed of the query. The result is returned ok (and quite fast) when I run the query manually. I think the problem is that the php can't hold all those results in memory to process them... But I needed the objects to view some of their values and calculate another one. That and I have a whole API I created that returns the Json of those tables.

Comment: @Quasdunk I don't want to paginate that data. I want to iterate through it, and calculate some stuff based on some attributes of each object.

Comment: @Thaenor Ok, pagination chunks the query under the hood, namely with `skip()` and `take()`: `User::skip($pageNumber * $resultsPerPage)->take($resultsPerPage)->get();` (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) - `skip` and `take` actually refer to the query builder and not on the result set, it translates to e.g. MySQL as `LIMIT offset, count`.

Comment: @Thaenor And by the way, if you have a Json API to fetch data, I think pagination fits just right, the docs even show an example of a beautiful Json Paginator: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#converting-results-to-json - and of course you can access and modify the results before returning them. Sorry if I'm missing your actual goal, just wanted to make sure you consider it, since it looks like a neat approach to what I think your problem is.

Comment: @Quasdunk probably not a good move, but when I wrote the client side I decided it was easier to let it handle the pagination, so it receives all the json data and divides it into pages showing a set number at a time. But I digress, at this point I have the model called "ticket" and I want to for each all of them (or at least a segment) and calculate points based on their attributes (I have the formula set up). But the issue here is I can't hold the data in memory - php blows up before I can even chunk it. what alternatives do I have? I'm thinking of storing it as some session variable or txt

Comment: @Thaenor Yep, I think you got yourself into some trouble by letting the client side handle the pagination :) You're now witnessing one of the many downsides of that, which is handling way more data than necessary instead of letting the client side just tell you which data / which portion it wants. If you have no way to revert that decision, I'm afraid the only solution is to assign way more memory to PHP :) (This obviously would be a really, really bad idea, it's expensive and doesn't scale at all). Otherwise, as you see, Laravel has really powerful pagination features ;)

Comment: @Quasdunk The issue I'm currently having and that let me to post this, isn't because of pagination. The method I'm doing actually is meant to do inner processing of data. So I want to take a set of objects, do stuff with them and save them back to the DB there's zero interaction with the client here. As for changing pagination I think that'll be a challenge because I went with a SPA for client side... it's been fully implemented and will take some changes...

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I'm posting this as an answer because it involves some code. I guess I've totally missed your point in the original question because I though that you were trying to return the whole result set to the client. If I'm still missing something, please leave a comment and I'll delete this answer.

> So I want to take a set of objects, do stuff with them and save them back to the DB

That's an easy one!

```
$chunkSize = 100; // or whatever your memory allows
$totalUsers = User::count();

$chunks = floor($totalUsers / $chunkSize);

for ($chunk = 0; $chunk <= $chunks; $chunk++) {

    $offset = $chunk * $chunkSize;

    $users = User::skip($offset)->take($chunkSize)->get();

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        // do something

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

If it takes too long, you'll probably get a timeout if you trigger this loop from HTTP, so you should probably run it from console.

Comment: I've been checking the error logs and I've found this weird 'PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)' - it's strange because php is allocating such a small amount of data (43 bytes) when php.ini memory limit is 1GB. After increasing the memory nothing happens still and now I don't even have the out of memory errors in the php log

Comment: @Thaenor You mean the error occured while running the above code? Because that should only take about as much memory as one chunkSize of records needs (+ some overhead), I don't think that's 128MB for 100 records. Looks like you've got a memory leak somewhere else then.

Comment: Another question I forgot to ask before. How do I trigger this from console? I currently have it configured as a route.... a secretRoute (but I still haven't coded the security part lol)
**PS:** sorry I didn't make it clear, the out of memory error mentioned in the first answer reports to the unoptimized code. The one you posted works wonders. THANK YOU so much!

Comment: @Thaenor There are lots of ways :) One could be to put the code into a Job: (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes - you don't need the queue part). You can then simply trigger it from a Controller like `$this->dispatch(new ModifyUsersJob);` (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dispatching-jobs-from-requests). To run it from console, just create an artisan command (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan) and dispatch the job from there.

Comment: One last thing, before we wrap this up (*and thank you very much for your patience and help*) - but can I refine the query to only select a group of users with a state? Like User::where('state','=','active')->skip(... ?

Comment: @Thaenor You're very welcome, that's what SO is for ;) And yes, you absolutely can define any constraints you like!

Comment: this is getting quite frustrating... now my php artisan doesn't recognize make:job...

Comment: @Thaenor Which version of Laravel are you using? It's called 'job' since L5.1, before it was called 'command', but it's the exact same thing. Just look at what `php artisan` (without any arguments) offers you. And make sure you're looking at the corresponding version of the docs (you can choose the version in the menu bar of the documentation website).

Comment: I'm using 5.0.3 I think. so they're called "commands" and not "jobs", that's why I've been looking at it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
        DB::table("table")
            ->select('column1', 'column2')
            ->orderBy('column2', 'asc')
            ->chunk(70000, function($users) {
            foreach ($users as $row) {
              // To do with data
           }
       }
```

Comment: It's been so long I've forgotten how I solved this issue. I think thats marginally similar to what I did 